# Writing traits as class templates vs variable templates?

Tags: c++

Pre-C++14 type traits were written like this:

```
struct A {};

template <typename T> struct is_A : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_A<A<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

C++14 variable templates lets us spell them like this:

```
struct A {};

template <typename T> constexpr bool is_A = false;
template <typename T> constexpr bool is_A<A<T>> = true;
```

Things in `<type_traits>` use the first form. Some newer stuff like `borrowed_range<T>` uses the second form.

Is there any *objective* reason to prefer one or the other? Or are they equivalent for all purposes except brevity?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Variable templates can also be partially specialized.

Comment: the first can be used as a type argument, obviously. THough I rarely saw it done outside standard library implementation itself

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any objective reason to prefer one or the other?

The first version is prefered if you want to be able to use your type trait in situations where a `bool` won't work, like with certain other standard library type traits, such as `std::conjunction`.

```cpp
template<class T>
struct A {};

template <class T> struct is_A : std::false_type {};
template <class T> struct is_A<A<T>> : std::true_type {};
template <class T> inline constexpr bool is_A_v = is_A<T>::value;

template<class... Ts>
std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<is_A<std::remove_cvref_t<Ts>>...>>
foo(Ts&&... args) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I feel `std::conjunction` itself is very rarely used. It does shortcircuiting, but I can't remember the last time I needed it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I use it quite frequently so that was the first thing that popped up :-)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The short-circuiting it provides is rather weak: all the arguments that are templates are instantiated. The only thing it does is prevent the evaluation of the member `value`, which in your case makes no difference. In such cases, I'd argue `(is_A<Ts> && ...)` is much clearer than `std::conjunction`.

Comment: @PasserBy cppreference says that it will not instantiate the rest of the `Ts` once the value can be determined. _"The short-circuit instantiation differentiates conjunction from fold expressions: a fold expression, like `(... && Bs::value)`, instantiates every `B` in `Bs`, while `std::conjunction_v<Bs...>` stops instantiation once the value can be determined. This is particularly useful if the later type is expensive to instantiate or can cause a hard error when instantiated with the wrong type."_

Comment: @TedLyngmo Huh, you're right, I completely misremembered. I'm apparently thinking of `std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<std::underlying_type_t<Ts>, int>...>` where only the first of `Ts` is an `enum`.

Answer (score 3):

The first form lets you do things like this:

```
void foo(std::false_type);
void foo(std::true_type);

template <typename T>
void bar(const T& value) {
    func(is_A<T>{});
}
```

But even that is a subjective benefit, because not everyone likes that style of code and you can achieve the same goals with `if constexpr` or `requires`, which makes sense because those are newer language features which evolved in the presence of C++14 variable templates.

So my answer is no, there's no objective benefit to one over the other in a general sense.